# Como atualizar UITableView com array bidimensional?

Tags: ios, swift

Não estou conseguindo atualizar minha `UITableView` com os dados contidos no *Array*:

```
var linha: NSArray = [["Categoria": "Desenvolvimento para IOS", "Imagem": "swift.png"],["Categoria": "Programação orientada a objeto", "Imagem": "php.png"]]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeViewCell

    cell.titulo.text = //
    cell.imagem.image = //

    return cell
}
```

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Tendo um **array** de **dictionaries**, como é o caso que você exemplificou, basta fazer algo assim:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return count(linha)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeViewCell

    let registro = linha[indexPath.row]

    cell.titulo.text = registro["Categoria"]
    cell.imagem.image = registro["Imagem"]

    return cell
}
```